# How to display Matlab figures on the website using python?

Tags: python, matlab, matlab-figure, echarts

Like the Pyecharts and Echarts, the figure in Matlab can easily interact with humans. Thus, I'd like to build a data visualization platform on web using the Matlab figure. I know Matlab provide a way to do this, but it's single and boring comparing with the Pyecharts(Echarts).
In addition, I know how to exhibit static images of Matlab figures on web, so you'd better not give this suggestion.
Finally, is there any idea to show Matlab figures on web using python? Appreciation for your comments.

Comment: “I know Matlab provide a way to do this, but it's single and boring” Are you saying you know how to do this, but don’t want to do it that way because it’s too easy? I don’t understand what this question is about, I guess.

Comment: Sorry to make you misunderstand. What I mean is that, when I take this way, the interface of web will be dull and old while python presents a more lively one.

Comment: Why not use a JavaScript library for graphing like ChartJS? Unless your doing some specialized plotting that only MATLAB can do.

Comment: To MichaelTr7: I have done a lot of work in Matlab, about 20 different functions to draw figure. Some picture is hard to duplicate on Python or JavaScript